# Deploying a JAR file on IBM Cloud

Tags: java, node.js, jar, ibm-cloud

I want to deploy a node.js workspace on IBM Cloud. The workspace contains a jar file. Is there any other way to deploy a JAR file exceptionally or the JAR gets uploaded along with the node.js files? I am calling the JAR file inside a function.
Just wanted to know whether the JAR file gets uploaded or not when I use the following command:

```
bx cf push
```

Comment: the jar should get deployed along with the nodejs files

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation from the Cloud Foundry docs ...

> **How cf push Finds the Application**
>
> By default, cf push recursively
>   pushes the contents of the current working directory. Alternatively,
>   you can provide a path using either a manifest or a command line
>   option.
>
> If the path is to a directory, cf push recursively pushes the contents
>   of that directory instead of the current working directory. If the
>   path is to a file, cf push pushes only that file.
>
> *Note: If you want to
>   push more than a single file, but not the entire contents of a
>   directory, consider using a .cfignore file to tell cf push what to
>   exclude.*
>
> ***Source: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html***

Based on this description, your jar file will get pushed.  If you want to stop it getting pushed, you could create a temporary `.cfignore` file, something like this:

```
if [[ condition ]]; then
    echo my.jar > .cfignore
    bx cf push
    rm -f .cfignore
else
    rm -f .cfignore 
    bx cf push
fi
```

If you already have a `.cfignore` you your logic will need to either remove or add your jar file to it.