# How to run jar file on IBM cloud

Tags: java, cloud, ibm-cloud

I'm new about IBM cloud and now I want to run my jar file (contain hello world) 
via IBM cloud. How I can do it step by step?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573331

Comment: actually I need for basic details about it.

Comment: Then add those details to the question? And I would assume you are familiar with Cloud Foundry? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/runtimes/liberty/getting-started.html#getting-started